# Database query failing in django views when using filter

Tags: django

Just going through the Django tutorial and am playing around and testing stuff.

My question is, how come the following line works and lets me go to page no problem:

```
test =  Choice.choices.all()
```

While the following filter line gives me the error message `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

```
test =  Choice.choices.get("question_id=6")
```

Even when I try the following two lines it doesn't work. No idea what's happening or why

```
test =  Choice.choices.get("question_id=6")[0]
test =  Choice.choices.get("question_id=6")[0].question_text
```

I feel like i need to really understand what's going on and why so I can actually do proper queries in the future

Comment: You should't wrap question_id=6 in ", try again after deleting them

Answer (score 0):

That's because of a syntax error. It should be:

```
test =  Choice.choices.get(question_id="6")
```

or, if the `question_id` field is `int` (pretty sure it is):

```
test =  Choice.choices.get(question_id=6)
```

Basically, what's inside the bracket (parameter) is the Django translation of a SQL `WHERE` condition, where you can specify what field and what value to include in the result.
Infact, it corresponds to: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE question_id=6`

You put this where condition inside a string, but the `.get()` method doesn't accept a string.

Let me know whether it works!